# Algorithm to determine if a polynomial has any complex roots

Tags: polynomials, rootfinding

Is there a simple algorithm to determine if a given polynomial (with all real coefficients) has all real roots? I do not need to know what the roots are; I just what to know if a given polynomial has any complex roots.

Background: I am aware that there are algorithms (for example see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.00410)) to compute all of the real roots of an arbitrary degree polynomial
\begin{equation}
\label{polynomial}
  a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \cdots + a_n x^n ,
\end{equation}
where $a_0,...,a_n$ are all real constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the companion matrix to find the roots via  eigenvalue calculation:

[Companion matrix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix)

Note that you have to consider Sturm's theorem in order to find the number of complex/real roots without explicitly calculating them (that's the only way):

[Sturm's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem)